# How to change only part of a register to a number (Examples are doing it wrong?)

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, binary-operators

I want to write for example the number 32 to the 16-24 bits of a register. This register is 100 bits long and the rest or some of the register contains "reserved bits" that shouldn't be write to (According to the datasheet.) or lets say it contains other values I don't want to change(Previous settings.).

If it was only a few bits I could set each one of them with the `R &= ~(1 << x)` or `R |= 1 << x` for each bit. But if it was a number, It'd be a huge pain to turn 32 to binary and do it one by one. I see some of the examples basically do something like `R = 0x20 << 16`. but I'm confused. wouldn't that ruin every other bit and set the reserved bits to 0 messing with the MCU Operation?

Comment: Use a [bit mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))?

Comment: can you elaborate more? You mean using & ~(bits I ant to zero) and |= bits I want to keep? that'd take a long time and be really annoying. (wait I can make a function that turns my number into binary and basically |= the actual number and &= the opposite number, is that what you mean)

Comment: What exactly it would mean in your case, I don't know (it has been years since I've done any assembly), but the point of a bit mask is to set several bits at once. See the Wikipedia article that I linked to.

Comment: I will make a macro for that. I just am curious since so many examples (even official cmsis in some places) just ignore it and set the registry all at once with the reserved bits being 0). also I'm doing C! I'm just working with cortex-m microcontrollers

Comment: _"According to the datasheet"_ - give is a clue, what is the part and what is the tool-chain?

Comment: @Clifford why does it matter? it's a general question about C. you should just see this as wanting to change some bits in middle of an array without changing anything else (like setting anything to a zero or one) without any data on what they currently are

Comment: @AmyGamble It is not a general question if you mention a specific data sheet. The unusual size of the register suggests that it is not memory mapped, and even if it were, there is no 100 bit data type in most tool chains or architectures outside of hardware description languages. The point is for such a large and unusually sized register, the most appropriate solution will be hardware and tool chain/language specific. If this is rather a hypothetical platform, then mention of a datasheet is misleading, and the scenario unlikely. Gates and die space would not normally be wasted in such a ...

Comment: manner, or a design made quite so inefficient or  awkward to code.

Comment: If it is a "general question about C" you should tag it as such or mention it in the question.

Comment: @Clifford Others have been very helpful already gave me my answer(despite the lack of datasheets and technicality). that was a theoretical example. Either way thanks for your help.

Comment: @AmyGamble indeed, but the issue of a 100bit register has not been addressed in any answer.  If that were important, the information I suggested would be necessary.  I am trying g to help by covering your whole question, but you seem less interested in this aspect than your question suggests.  You should perhaps edit the question to make the "theoretical" hardware more realistic (to fit the accepted answer perhaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to write for example the number 32 to the 16-24 bits of a register. This register is 100 bits long and the rest or some of the register contains "reserved bits" that shouldn't be write to (According to the datasheet.) or lets say it contains other values I don't want to change(Previous settings.).

You want to perform a [Read-Modify-Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93modify%E2%80%93write). In this case, you are interested in setting bits 16-24 to a specific value. Assuming those values are zero, you can do that like this:

```
my_register |= (32 << 16);
```

This is a Bitwise-OR operation and that is important to note because it keeps whatever the value of the bits were.

Assuming those values are non-zero, you will want to clear those bits first, then write the new value. You can do that like this:

```
my_register &= ~(0xFF << 16); //Clear bits 16-24
my_register |= (0x20 << 16); //Set bits 16-24 to 32
```

The above uses Bitwise AND, Bitwise OR, and Bitwise inversion. Again, these operations maintain the values of other bits.

> I see some of the examples basically do something like R = 0x20 << 16.
>   but I'm confused. wouldn't that ruin every other bit and set the
>   reserved bits to 0 messing with the MCU Operation?

That's not necessarily true. Those bits are likely write protected, or the default value for those bits might be 0 so writing 0 to them has no effect. It just depends on the MCU itself.

Comment: Oh thanks :) I mostly saw it 1 or 2 places eitherway. and the libraries where from the vendors (CMSIS initialization for the clock etc.) so that explains why. they probably knew it's okay.

Comment: You have not dealt with the fact that this register is an unlikely 100 bit value, which begs the question if how it is addressed or accessed and by what data type.  That unlikely constraint makes the question unanswerable without further information.  However it appears to be an invented constraint, so perhaps it does not matter in practice.

Comment: Note, technically, this approach is still "writing reserved bits that shouldn't be written to" - just with the value they had before, which might or might not be relevant, depending on the hardware implementation. There's simply no "single bit write" in C - In some assembly languages, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here a function for understanding the principe:

```
unsigned SetSomeBits(unsigned Var, unsigned StartBitNumber, unsigned NumberOfBits, unsigned Value2Set)
{
  unsigned Mask = (1<<NumberOfBits)-1; //With NumberOfBits=3 Mask becomes 0b000111 
  Mask <<= StartBitNumber;
  //Mask contains now 0 at do-not-touch  bit positions
  //Mask contains now 1 at to-be-changed bit positions

  Var &= ~Mask; //Zero out the to-be-changed bits

  return Var | (Value2Set<<StartBitNumber); //Set the requested bits
}
```

...and here as a macro:

```
#define SET_SOME_BITS(Var, StartBitNumber, NumberOfBits, Value2Set) ((Var) & ~(((1<<(NumberOfBits))-1)<<(StartBitNumber)) | (Value2Set)<<(StartBitNumber))
```

Both versions fail if Value2Set doesn't fit into NumberOfBits.